# Converting Tables to Ansi Padding On

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, ansi-sql

I am currently working with a MSSQL 2008R2 Server and a database which uses a lot of tables that are a mixed bag of ANSI_PADDED Settings. 90% of the tables habe Columns with Ansi Padding on AND columns with Ansi Padding off.

I have now been tasked with "converting" those tables so that every column uses Ansi_Padding ON.

I would like to know which is the easiest way to do this?
I am suposed to write a script which "converts" one table but in the end I am going to need a script which changes all the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the column without changing any of the properties after turning the ANSI_PADDING setting on:

```
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
ALTER TABLE dbo.test ALTER COLUMN prolemColumn varchar(30)
```

If you run sp_help before and after that syntax you can see that the TrimTrailingBlanks setting has changed.